# How to use dispatcher

Tags: windows-phone-7

how to use dispatcher.BeginInvoke in for loop( httpwebrequest).With each dispatcher.BeginInvoke have complete before call another dispatcher.BeginInvoke. Because objects return by httpwerequest are wrong position.

Answer (score 3):

No, `BeginInvoke` is asynchronous - you're basically adding delegates to a queue of items to be executed on the UI thread.

If you need to wait until the delegate has executed before you continue work in your background thread, you'll need to do a bit of work yourself, as Silverlight doesn't support the synchronous `Dispatcher.Invoke` method, or the `DispatcherOperation.Wait()` method. Silverlight tries to avoid synchronous approaches like this - if you can possibly redesign your code so that you *don't* need to wait, that would be preferable.

Comment: 'if you can possibly redesign your code so that you don't need to wait, that would be preferable.' +1, for instance you can implement a 'queue' of pending requests.

Comment: what's method help me  know dispatcher end?

Comment: @abc: I'm not sure there *is* anything which makes that simple in Silverlight, precisely because the idea is to not have dependencies between the threads. You could use `Monitor.Wait`, and pulse the object from the delegate you're executing on the dispatcher thread, but it's pretty ugly...

Answer (score 0):

Being able to easily convert a synchronous sequence of operations into asynchrounous code has been a subject I've blogged about a fair bit.  If you want to take up my approach you will need to add the following (relatively small) chunks of code:

- [The core AsyncOperationService](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2011/07/30/simple-asynchronous-operation-runner-ndash-revisited.aspx#aosCode)
- [Code to create an AsyncOperation from the .NET Async Pattern](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2011/08/27/using-asyncoperationservice-with-the-.net-asynchronous-pattern.aspx#fromasyncpattern)
- [A couple of Extension methods for WebRequest](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2011/09/10/the-asyncoperationservice-and-httpwebrequest.aspx#webeequestextensions)

Here is some example code that has the flavour of what you describe in your question:-

```
IEnumerable<AsyncOperation> LoadSomeStuff(IList<string> urls)
{
    for (string url in urls)
    {
         yield return AsyncOperationService.SwitchToBackgroundThread();
         WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url);
         WebResponse resp = null;
         yield return req.GetResponseAsyncOp(r => resp = r);
         using (resp)
         {
             // Do stuff with the Web Response such as construct model class instances from a stream.
         }

         // When ready to actually start touching the UI

         yield return AsyncOperationService.SwitchToUIThread();

         // Do stuff to the UI

    }

}
```

usage:

```
List<string> urls = new List<string> {"pinkElephants.xml", "whileElephants.xml"}
LoadSomeStuff(urls).Run(err =>
{
     if (err == null)
     {
          // Cool, it all worked and I probably don't need to do anything
     }
     else
     {
          // Something bad happened, lets tell the user about it in the UI somehow.
     }

});
```

Note that this isn't the most efficient code possible. However in many cases the time it takes  HTTP response to be delivered massively out-weighs the time the rest of the code uses up so the inefficiency can be quite small and well worth the reduced complexity of code.